# Get JavaScript calculated value to Struts action

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeFunc() {
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selectedValue);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
<option value="1">Option #1</option>
<option value="2">Option #2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Can we get the selectedvalue back in the JSP as onChange parameter and pass it to form as a hidden variable and take it back to struts action ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get javascript calculated value in the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671921/how-to-get-javascript-calculated-value-in-the-form)

Comment: *down vote favorite* :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question actually is--put the value into the hidden form property, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I have added jquery line to populate the hidden field value in  JSP
Hidden field in JSP

So whenever the radio button is clicked, jquery helps me populate my hidden field value.

It worked, thanks

```
<html:hidden name="annualPremSizeCreditForm" property="selectedRadioButtonID" value=""/>

    var radioButtonIdDesc = $('input[type=radio][name=radioButtons]:checked').attr('id');
                        if((radioButtonIdDesc).indexOf("fifteenPercentRadio") != -1){
                            $('input[name=selectedRadioButtonID]').val("fifteenPercentRadio");
                        }
                        if((radioButtonIdDesc).indexOf("tenPercentRadio") != -1){
                            $('input[name=selectedRadioButtonID]').val("tenPercentRadio");
                        }
```